# Is there any way to hide available classes from Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Not a practical question but just curious if anybody knows:
In the Identity Inspector, you can choose a custom class for a view.
There is a dropdown, which seemingly magically populates all available `NSView` subclasses in the project.

Seeing that I can't explicitly `#import` any headers, and I also did not drag in any `Objects` into the "Document Outline"

I'm curious as to how IB knows of all of my `NSView` subclasses.
Though there would be no reason to, is there any way to hide an `NSView` subclass from IB?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same basic way that it does code completion in your source files. Xcode leverages Clang to index your project, including both your source files and imported modules.

Comment: Is there a build setting that I can modify to change the files that are indexed?  Or does it literally just go through all files in the root folder of the project?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what files it indexes, but presumably at least those which are members of the currently active target and its dependencies. I don't think there's a build setting.